# How to configure Django and Nginx to allow access of static files with docker?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to run a docker-compose container with Django and nginx but I can't access any static html or css even if lookin at the containers' app log all seems fine.

I'm probably messing up with paths and permissions and I don't know where is the issue.

Here is my settings.py file splitted in images because stackoverflow flagged the post as spam:

1. [InstalledApps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B7e2.png)
2. [Middleware_templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlDW5.png)
3. [database_auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euzzl.png)
4. [staticurl_staticroot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOg4m.png)

Here is my docker compose.yml:

```
`# Specifies Docker compose version
version: "3.9"

services:
  djangoapp:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
      - SECRET_KEY=${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=${DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS}
      - OPENAI_KEY=${OPENAI_KEY}
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}

  proxy:
    build:
      # project folder name
      context: ./proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/static
volumes:
  postgres-data:
  static-data:`
```

My proxy dockerfile:

```
`FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:latest
LABEL maintainer="londonappdeveloper.com"

COPY ./default.conf.tpl /etc/nginx/default.conf.tpl
COPY ./uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
COPY ./run.sh /run.sh
ENV LISTEN_PORT=8000
ENV APP_HOST=djangoapp
ENV APP_PORT=9000

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static && \
    chmod 755 /vol/static && \
    touch /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    chown nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    chmod +x /run.sh

VOLUME /vol/static
USER nginx

CMD ["/run.sh"]`
```

My default.conf.tpl file :

```
upstream django {
    server djangoapp:${APP_PORT}; 
}
 
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:${LISTEN_PORT};
    error_log /dev/stdout debug;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    #server_name kurai.domain;
    location /kurai{
        alias /vol/static/;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass              django;
        include                 /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        client_max_body_size    10M;
    }
}
```

And finally my run.sh for proxy:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
envsubst < /etc/nginx/default.conf.tpl > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

When I try to access : http://127.0.0.1/kurai/login or http://127.0.0.1/admin i get an
'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'.

Comment: `compose.yml` does seem broken: note that `\`# Specifies` (first line) only ends in `static-data:\`` (last line). Suspicious or copy+paste error at least. Please double-check.

Comment: ` was added by stackoverflow , it is present at the beginning an in the end of almost every code block that I have pasted.